# getElementsByTagName for two tags at once

Tags: javascript

I use this:

```
function setFontSize() {
   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
      p[i].style.fontSize = selectedsize+"px"
   }
}
```

What's the simplest and best way to throw in 'th' too?

Comment: `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Why not add a class on the `<table>` element, and then `#table.big-fonts td { font-size: 125% }` stuff. Querying all the cells manually and writing their `style` is not a good approach.

Comment: @elclanrs Think outside of the box. Why walk the DOM to find all cells when you can just set a class name on the table?

Comment: I didn't know about querySelectorAll. Reading up on that now. Thanks.

Comment: With my limited insight I would just love to not batch through my whole site to add a class to the tables that I consider default styled tables.

Comment: There's talk about querySelectorAll being much slower, over here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have to support older browsers you can use `document.querySelectorAll(..)`.

```
function setFontSize() {
   var i;
   var p = document.querySelectorAll('td, tr');
   for( i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ) {
      p[i].style.fontSize = selectedsize + "px"
   }
}
```

Comment: if you do, you could use p.concat(document.getElementsByTagName('th'));

Answer (score 0):

```
function setFontSize() {
   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
       ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th'),
       val = selectedsize + "px";
   for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
      p[i].style.fontSize = val;
      ths[i].style.fontSize = val;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would probably use this. Looks like what I want. But I couldn't get it to work. It changed font-size in some places only. I'll try to explain better, soon.

Comment: Just post a fiddle with your HTML + JS code and let's see what is possible to do ;)

Comment: Yes. ;) This is the script: http://flamencopeko.net/styleswitch.js. (Although I'm trying to learn I'm way off on where to use or not var, ;, space, etc.) It's called from footer.php (Because the pages has to load before the tags can be styled. This causes an unwanted display of standard style between pages.) The buttons for choosing styles (table-width and font-size) is in http://flamencopeko.net/toc.php. This is the code: http://flamencopeko.net/toc.txt.

Comment: Ait. It does work. Any idèas why it would not play well with your code? I tried this: http://flamencopeko.net/styleswitch_two_tags.js, and it like makes the top-most text large, then "gives up" on seemingly random places on the pages.

Comment: Maybe because there are no `<th>` elements in the page?